# Evaluating a literal as an expression (Scheme)

Tags: scheme, expression, literals, evaluation

I am attempting to evaluate a literal as an expression in Scheme (using Guile currently).  Example:

```
(define x '(+ 6 6))
(define y (evaluate-literal x))     ; Expected result:  y = 12
```

(Here, `evaluate-literal` is a placeholder for what I'm looking for.)  Is there a lisp function/idiom that allows this to be done?  The reason why I need to do this is because the expression may be invalid at the time of definition, but would be a valid expression later when it is evaluated.

---

Currently my workaround solution is to use `delay` and `force` but it's not very elegant:

```
(define x (delay (+ 6 6)))
(define y (force x))
```

Comment: You can use `eval`, I suppose. But I would consider the `delay` or even plain `lambda` to be more preferable.

Comment: How would you use `lambda` in this scenario?

Comment: @fyl I edited my answer showing how to use `lambda`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `eval`, although difficult to use safely. See this [post](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html) to see the reasons why.

```
(define x '(+ 6 6))
(define y (eval x))
```

Using the built-in `delay/force` procedures is a fine solution:

```
(define x (delay (+ 6 6)))
(define y (force x))
```

Or, as has been suggested in the comments, you could use a `lambda` for implementing your own `delay/force` syntax:

```
(define-syntax my-delay
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((my-delay object)
     (lambda () object))))

(define (my-force delayed-object)
  (delayed-object))

(define x (my-delay (+ 6 6)))
(define y (my-force x))
```

The above is a toy implementation, a real-world implementation would memoize the result for avoiding the need to call the `lambda` each time, but you get the idea.

Comment: The solutions using delay/force or a lambda are *vastly preferable* to the solution using eval. For more on the difficulty of using eval safely, see Matthew Flatt's blog post on this topic: http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html

Comment: Matthew Flatt's blog is ablour #lang Racket but eval in Scheme R5RS works different